# clearfix does not work in the large view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code of Bootstrap Framework `bootstrap-3.3.6-dist` and when I render it in Firefox browser I am getting just two column in the full Screen. The Thing with this line `<div class="clearfix visable-md"></div>` I added it because there an error in the rendering when going from the large to the medium view but I do not have any idea why the 4 columns are being rendered in the large view and just 2 columns are being rendered?

**code**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">




    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 1</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. Now set offended own out required entirely. Especially occasional mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put boy carried chiefly shy general. 
        </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 2</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. 
        </div>


      <div class="clearfix visable-md"></div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 3</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. Now set offended own out required entirely. Especially ocd too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put 
        </div>



      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 4</h4>
        Hadi if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye theown out required entireloccasional mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put boy carried chiefly shy general. 
        </div>


        </div>

      </div>


      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

`visable-md`

It should be

`visible-md`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your clear fix div change `<div class="clearfix visable-md"></div>` to `<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">




    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 1</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. Now set offended own out required entirely. Especially occasional mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put boy carried chiefly shy general. 
        </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 2</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. 
        </div>


      <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 3</h4>
        Had strictly mrs handsome mistaken cheerful. We it so if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye then form. To easy five less if rose were. Now set offended own out required entirely. Especially ocd too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put 
        </div>



      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
      <h4>Colums 4</h4>
        Hadi if resolution invitation remarkably unpleasant conviction. As into ye theown out required entireloccasional mrs discovered too say thoroughly impossible boisterous. My head when real no he high rich at with. After so power of young as. Bore year does has get long fat cold saw neat. Put boy carried chiefly shy general. 
        </div>


        </div>

      </div>


      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

See Bootply http://www.bootply.com/AzBfrv72GA